# how to control space between radiobuttons of the radiobuttonlist control

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am having lot of space between newly added radiobuttons(yes and No) of the RadioButtonList and the first part of the existing  region(divName) is aligned properly.
can any body help me in aligning the newly added second  region(div1)

```
<div id="divpanelFacts" runat="server">
            <fieldset id="panelFacts">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                 <td>
                            <div id="divName" runat="server" visible="false">                          
                                <span>
                                    <label runat="server" id="Label1">
                                        <span id="pNameSpan" runat="server">*</span>P Name</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="textPName" runat="server" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                          <td>                    

                            <div id="div1" runat="server" visible="false">                           
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Would like to use this option for document purpose"></asp:Label>                               
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" TextAlign="Left" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" Selected="True" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>                           
                            </div>

                          </td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try adding some Css properties to the control? Like: Display:Inline or Inline-block? The go to the chrome console and review the size of each element to see if the problem is about height or width.

Answer (score 0):

Your table width is at 100%, which means it's going to stretch it, and table I think takes precedence.